# Best practice for deploying low traffic rails app without cost concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

### My questions

#### Cost related pit falls to avoid when deploying rails app?

Attacks are welcome as it would teach me what to expect and brace myself against.
I would rather avoid big bills at the end of month, however.

#### Easy cloud hosting services to use?

I picked AWS because it seems scalable and I thought I can avoid leaning another service later.
I have no regrets but AWS is overwhelming, if there was significantly simpler service, I should have used it.

#### My current concern

- Dos attack or get request flooding on aws S3 could raise hosting cost significantly as I'm uploading some contents there.

Billing alarm is useful, but without automatic shutdown I feel a little uncomfortable taking a break and going into a jungle or an inhabited island where I get no INTERNET connection to be informed of or to shut down my service...

#### Obvious fix for my case

Stop using S3 and save user uploads to database where I can control scaling behavior. But then, most people seems to be using S3 with carrierwave, why?

#### What I'm doing

Making my first ever home page using:

- elastic beanstalk
- rails5
- Carrierwave gem configured to save user uploads in S3

#### Edit

---

In the end, I could not find any real solution to the no cap for S3 issue.

The below is more or less my note.
I'm guessing S3 has some basic built in defense against attacks because I have not heard of sad stories about people using S3 to host static web sites and getting a bill over 10000 US, which can still happen though regardless of how good amazon's defense might be.

#### mitigation

A script that periodically checks for s3 log files and calls an action that disables s3 resource serving when the cumulative size of those files is too large.
S3 log sometimes takes more than an hour before they become available, so it's no solution but better than nothing.

```
class LogObserver
  def initialize
    aws_conf = Aws.config.update({
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      region: 'ap-northeast-1'})
    @bucket_name="bucket name that holds s3 log"

    @last_checked_log_timestamp = Time.now.utc
    log "started at: #{Time.now}"
  end

  def run
    bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(@bucket_name)
    while true
      prv_log_ts = @last_checked_log_timestamp
      log_size = fetch_log_size(bucket)

      log "The total size of S3 log accumulated since last time this script was executed: #{log_size}"

      time_range = @last_checked_log_timestamp - prv_log_ts # float
      log_size_per_second = log_size/time_range

      if log_size_per_second > (500.kilobyte/60)
        log "Disabling S3 access as S3 log size is greater than expected."

        `curl localhost/static_pages/disable_s3`
      end

      sleep 60*60 
    end
  end
  def log text
    puts text
    File.open('./s3_observer_log.txt','a') do |f|
      f << text
    end
  end

  def fetch_log_size(bucket)
    log_size=0
    bucket.objects(prefix: 'files').each do |o|
      time_object = o.last_modified


      if time_object < @last_checked_log_timestamp
        next
      end
      @last_checked_log_timestamp = time_object
      log_size += o.size.to_i
    end  
    return log_size
  end
end
```

Rake task:

```
namespace :s3_log do
  desc "Access S3 access log files and check their cumulative size. If the size is above the expected value, disables s3 access."
  task :start_attack_detection_loop do
    require './s3_observer.rb'
    id=Process.fork do
      o=LogObserver.new
      o.run
    end
    puts "Forked a new process that watches s3 log. Process id: #{id}"
  end
end
```

controller action:

```
  before_action :ensure_permited_ip, only: [:enable_s3, :disable_s3]
  def enable_s3
    # allow disabling s3 only from localhost
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 3 
    end
  end
  def disable_s3
    # allow disabling s3 only from localhost
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 0 
    end
  end
  private
  def ensure_permited_ip
    if request.remote_ip!= "127.0.0.1" # allow access only from localhost
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Gems:

```
gem 'aws-sdk-rails'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experiences are limited but my suggestions would be:

> Cost related pit falls to avoid when deploying rails app?

- if you're gonna be using a background-job, use `rufus-scheduler` instead of `sidekiq` or `delayed_job`, because it runs on top of your `rails server` and would not require additional memory / additional dedicated processes. This allows you to procure the smallest/cheapest possible instance: t2.nano, which I did once before.

> Easy cloud hosting services to use?

- Heroku would be a good choice, because it is a lot easy to set it up. However if you're doing this for the experience, I would suggest to procure unmanaged hosting like [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/) or [Linode](https://www.linode.com/). I recently migrated my server from AWS to [Vpsdime](https://vpsdime.com/) 3 months ago because it's cheap and has big memory; so far so good.

> My current concern

- For `carrierwave`, you may restrict S3 access. See [reference](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Secure-uploaded-file-in-S3-and-make-it-only-accessible-by-supplying-secret-token%3F). This then prevents hotlinking and would then require a user to view your Rails pages first in order to download or view or show the S3 files. Now that Rails now have control over the S3 files, you can just simply use something like [Rack::Attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) to prevent DDOS or excessive requests. If your Rails app is configured with `Apache` or `Nginx`, you can instead set up DDOS rules there instead of using `Rack::Attack`. Or, if you are gonna be using AWS load balancer to manage / route the requests, then you can use [AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/) ... haven't really used this yet though.

Comment: Thanks @Jay-Ar Polidario. I did not expect to get such a concise answer so quick. Hmm, I'm already using signed url, but it's time based expiry and not access count. Setting it to expire in 1 second, however, should necessitate fairly frequent access to rails for flooding s3, so I guess I could try to capture attackers there.

Comment: no worries! :) I'm sure there are still better or more efficient ways that what I currently know, but I'm glad I could help.